# How to set image size in UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uibutton, scale

I'm trying to make a clone of decimal pad by stack views and UIButtons.
But when I try to make "Backspace" button image inside of it scales to the bounds of button.

How could I make image scale smaller than button itself?

Comment: whats your image size?

Comment: make content to .center in attribute inspector

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I have 70x70 pdf with space from bounds

Comment: i haven't any code. It is just setting for View Controller

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There may be two options to fix the problem.

1. Set the content mode to **.scaleAspectFit** and the image should not go out of the bounds :
   `myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`
2. Adjust the image insets:
   `myLikesButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer applies -- at least it doesn't work for iOS 13-15.

Answer (score 3):

Sanket was close:

2. Adjust the image insets: 
   Button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 40, 40, 40)

**The (40, 40, 40, 40) is just an example button sizing and you can adjust it to your satisfaction. Like Sanket answered (Top, Left, Bottom, Right) is what you should use, just adjust with actual numbers.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 15

```
  let button = UIButton()
  var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
  config.imagePadding = 40
  button.configuration = config
  return button
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you should keep in mind while loading image to the 'UIBUTTON'

- Try to use image size of 24*24 image when you are loading images to UIBARBUTTONIMAGE.
- When loading image in normal 'UIBUTTON' the image should be compatible with the button.
- Try the button with standard image size which is 32*32.
- In the right interface builder in storyboard try with Aspect fit.